# Why am I getting this error : Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types '[String]?' and 'String'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps, ipad

so i am new to swift and i am experimenting with google maps.
I cant figure out why does this line works :

**let state = p?.administrativeArea != nil ? p?.administrativeArea : "nil6"**

but not this line :

**let areaOfInterest = p?.areasOfInterest != nil ? p?.areasOfInterest : "nil7"**

I am getting this error message on the areaOfInterest line :

**Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types '[String]?' and 'String'**

Thanks in advance.

```
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil
        {
            print(error)
        }
        else
        {

            let p = placemarks?[0]

            print(p)
            let subThoroughfare = p?.subThoroughfare != nil ? p?.subThoroughfare : "nil1"
            let thoroughfare = p?.thoroughfare != nil ? p?.thoroughfare : "nil2"
            let country = p?.country != nil ? p?.country : "nil3"
            let postal = p?.postalCode != nil ? p?.postalCode : "nil4"
            let city = p?.locality != nil ? p?.locality : "nil5"
            let state = p?.administrativeArea != nil ? p?.administrativeArea : "nil6"
            let areaOfInterest = p?.areasOfInterest != nil ? p?.areasOfInterest : "nil7"

            self.addressLabel.text = "\(subThoroughfare!) \(thoroughfare!) \n \(city!), \(state!) \n \(country!) \(postal!)"
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This because all of the other properties you are accessing of a placemark are strings, except for the areas of interest, which is an (optional) array of stings. You are trying to cast it when there is no way it can work.

If you really want to format your errors like that, you can just use:

`let areaOfInterest = p?.areasOfInterest != nil ? p?.areasOfInterest : ["nil7"]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put ["nil7"] instead of "nil7"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help